# how can I send a fullCalendar event to controller to save it in the data base

Tags: javascript, symfony, fullcalendar

*how can I send a fullCalendar event to controller to save it in the data base*

```js
eventClick: function(presta) {
    let fs = document.getElementById("selection")
    let url = `/api/${presta.event.id}/edit`
    let debut = presta.event.start
    let end = presta.event.end

    let donnees = {
     "title": presta.event.title,
     "start": presta.event.start,
      "end": presta.event.end,
        }
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
    let test = xhr.open("POST", url,true)
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(donnees))      
  }
```

Comment: That seems to be the general approach to take, as shown in your code. Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: if the ajax requets works and send the data to controller, so you can retrieve the sended data with Request. `$title = $request->request->get('title')`